# How to center CustomItem in LazyRow vertically so that each item is in the center of The LazyRow?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried using a ContraintLayout to center it vertically as shown below. Nothing happens after I run the app, it stays in the same position. However, I used this same code snippet in my button and it seems to center it along side LazyRow.

**Note**: I am trying to accomplish this without modifying padding

**Logic I am trying to use to center vertically** (NOT WORKING)

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
    .padding(top = padding, bottom = padding)
    .constrainAs(item) {centerVerticallyTo(lazyRow)}, // center vertically to the lazy row NOT WORKING

                        ) {
                            CustomItem(data[index],  itemWidth, isMiddleIndex)
                            Text(
                                text = isMiddleIndex.toString() + " " + midIndex + listState.firstVisibleItemIndex % data.size + 1,
                                Modifier.size(16.dp)
                            )
                        }
```

Below is most of what I have so far

```kotlin
ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.Green)) {
            val (prevButton, nextButton, lazyRow, item) = createRefs()
            LazyRow(
                state = listState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .offset(y = 100.dp)
                    .background(color = Color.Green)
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                    .constrainAs(lazyRow) {
                    }
                    ,
                contentPadding = (contentPadding),
                flingBehavior = rememberSnapperFlingBehavior(
                    listState,
                    SnapOffsets.Center,
                    snapIndex = { _, startIndex, targetIndex ->
                        targetIndex.coerceIn(startIndex - 7, startIndex + 7)
                    })
            )
            {
                items(
                    count = if (isEndless) Int.MAX_VALUE else data.size,
                    itemContent = {
                        val index = it % data.size
                        val itemHeight =
                            if (index == midIndex) screenHeight / 8 * 6 else screenHeight / 8 * 5
                        val itemWidth =
                            if (index == midIndex) screenWidth / 8 * 6 else screenWidth / 8 * 6
                        val padding = if (index == midIndex) 0.dp else 0.dp
                        val isMiddleIndex = (index == midIndex)
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(top = padding, bottom = padding)
                                .constrainAs(item) {
                                 centerVerticallyTo(lazyRow) // center vertically to the lazy row NOT WORKING
                                },

                        ) {
                            CustomItem(data[index],  itemWidth, isMiddleIndex)
                            Text(
                                text = isMiddleIndex.toString() + " " + midIndex + listState.firstVisibleItemIndex % data.size + 1,
                                Modifier.size(16.dp)
                            )
                        }
                    })
            }
}
```

This is how it appears **not centered vertically**. Green represents LazyRow full constraints
[image: Not centered]

This is how it should appear when **centered vertically**
[image: Centered vertically]

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, why `LazyRow(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically)` doesn't work

Comment: @FishHawk Wait I think that may have fixed my problem

Comment: @FishHawk That fixed it!! Thank you. I tried everything else but that... I just started learning compose last week so its been tricky for me.